# jQuery Mobile: Why are onClick and onKeyPress events not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, onclick, onkeypress

In my jQuery Mobile code, I have some onClick and onKeyPress events but they are not firing. I am converting my client's website to a mobile version that includes lot of javascript functions. I don't know if it works if I convert everything into jQuery but I prefer not to do so and would like to keep the javascript functions as it is.

Is there a way to make this work entirely with javascript and not with jQuery?

`onClick="javascript:alert('test');"` seems to work fine. It's just the functions that are not being called.

http://jsfiddle.net/jetlag/CtkTV/1/

HTML:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="textA">Input A</label>
  <input class="inputField" id="textA" value="" type="text" onFocus="javascript:clearText(this);" value="This is default text A" />
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="textB">Input B</label>
  <input class="inputField" id="textB" value="" type="text" onKeyPress="javascript:keyPressEvent(e);" onFocus="javascript:clearText(this);" value="This is default text B" />
 </div>
 <div class="ui-grid-b">
   <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="button" id="goButton" onClick="javascript:goButtonPress();" value="Go" />
   </div>
   <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="button" id="testButton" onClick="javascript:alert('Alerted!');" value="Alert" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function keyPressEvent(e) {
  var evt = e || window.event;
  var keyPressed = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
  if (keyPressed == 13) {
    document.getElementById('goButton').click();
    evt.cancel = true;
  }
}

function goButtonPress() {
  alert('Button Pressed");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the keyPressEvent is in the global namespace? If you open the javascript console and enter "keyPressEvent" or "window.keyPressEvent" does it give you a function, or undefined?

Comment: Your fiddle is set to run `onLoad`, which means the JavaScript code you provided will be defined inside of `window.onload`, and therefore not available globally (especially to inline event handlers)

Comment: @Ian Yes you are right. That was the reason it wasn't working in jsFiddle. However in my html file, I have a large chunk of code inside the <body> tag and then have <script> tag just before </body>. Is this causing an issue? I am unable to resolve this in my HTML file.

Comment: @Ian Thanks. I missed to mention that in my answer. However still it is going to throw the error for `e`. In my fiddle i have it wrapped in the head to make the functions available for the inline events.

Comment: @PSL I definitely wasn't saying that was the *only* problem, but the immediate reason why functions couldn't be called in the fiddle anyways

Comment: @user1448031 I think that would be fine then. But there are other issues with your code that the answers here have pointed out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no `e` it should be `event` in your markup. i.e `javascript:keyPressEvent(event)`

```
 <input class="inputField" id="textB" value="" type="text" onKeyPress="javascript:keyPressEvent(event);" onFocus="javascript:clearText(this);" value="This is default text B" />
```

Also 
Your quotes are at wrong:-

```
function goButtonPress() {
  alert('Button Pressed"); <-- here quotes should match
}
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zt8h9/)

See [events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html)

Comment: Yes that's working. Thanks for correcting the typo, etc. The main reason was I had fiddle set to `onLoad` as mentioned in the comments above. But a similar script is not working in my HTML. See the comments below my question. Let me know if you know how to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: @user1448031 DO you see any errors in the console, if it reaches your event at all etc.?

Comment: It's all good now. There were some silly mistakes in my code. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/aLB6T/

While there's nothing wrong with inline java script you should not use it when working with jQuery Mobile. Because of its architecture it can cause big problems. That is why if possible use classic jQuery.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $(document).on('click', '#testButton', function(){ 
        alert('Alerted!');       
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#goButton', function(){ 
        alert('Button Pressed');      
    });        

    $(document).on('keypress', '#textB, #textA', function(evt){ 
        var keyPressed = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
        alert(keyPressed);
        if (keyPressed == 13) {
            document.getElementById('goButton').click();
            evt.cancel = true;
        }     
    });    
});
```

Comment: Yes I personally prefer using jQuery but for this particular project I am doing, I've to stick with Javascript. Thanks for your input.